# I want to give the RSA public key to the client

Tags: mfc, rsa

I am making clients and servers with MFC.
On the server, create a public key before Accept. I'm trying to send a public key to the client using the Send function, but a strange value is sent.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odCg9.png)

I thought I should send the public key of int value to char, so I used printf, but is there a better way?

function(RSA Function)

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "encryption.h"


Encryption::Encryption() {};
Encryption::~Encryption() {};

// p, q
void Encryption::Selectpq() 
{
    int random;
    int i, j;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    random = (rand() % 1000); 
    int ck, ck2 = 0;
    for (i = random; 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 2; j < i / 2 + 1; j++)
        {
            if (i%j == 0)
            {
                ck = 1;
                break;
            }
            ck = 0;
        }
        if (ck == 0 && ck2 == 1)
        {
            second = i;
            break;
        }
        if (ck == 0 && ck2 == 0)
        {
            first = i;
            ck2 = 1;
        }
    
    }
}
//pi e (1 < e < pi)
void Encryption::SelectEulerETC()
{
    int i, j, tmp = 1;
    pub_Key_First = first * second;
    eulerPi = (first - 1) * (second - 1);
    for (i = 2; i < eulerPi; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (i%j == 0 && eulerPi%j == 0)
                tmp = j;
        }
        if (tmp == 1)
        {
            pub_Key_Second = i;
            break;
        }
        tmp = 1;
    }
}
//d
void Encryption::SelectPriKey()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i < eulerPi; i++)
    {
        if ((pub_Key_Second * i) % eulerPi == 1)
            pri_Key = i;
    }
}

c = m^e mod n
void Encryption::Enc(char buffer[], int bufsize)
{
    for (int k = 0; k == bufsize; k++)
    {
        encrypt[k] = buffer[k];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < bufsize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pub_Key_Second; j++) // c = m^e mod n
        {
            sum *= (int)encrypt[i]; 
            sum %= pub_Key_First;
            encryptDone[j] = sum;
        }
    
    }
}
// m = c^d mod n
void Encryption::Decryption(char buffer[], int bufsize)
{
    while (decrypt != bufsize)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pri_Key; j++)
        {
            word = buffer[j];
            sum *= word; // m = c^d mod n
            sum %= pub_Key_First;
            decryptDone[j] = sum;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Server(Make Public key part)

```
//accept 
        CString str;
        CString ConnectInfo_str;
        CString ConnectInfo_str2;

        while (1)
        {
            //ACCEPT 
            enc.Selectpq();
            enc.SelectEulerETC();
            enc.SelectPriKey();

            tcpserver.ClntAccept();
            if (clnt_sock == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                break;
            }
```

server(send part)

```
    CServerDlg *dlg = (CServerDlg *)AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd;
    SOCKET socket = (SOCKET)p;
    
    char encPubKey_First[BUFSIZE];
    char encPubKey_Second[BUFSIZE];
    sprintf(encPubKey_First, "%u", enc.pub_Key_First);
    sprintf(encPubKey_Second, "%u", enc.pub_Key_Second);
    send(socket, encPubKey_First, sizeof(encPubKey_First), 0);
    while (1)
    {
        //recv
        
        tcpserver.ServRecv(socket); 
        if (tcpserver.recvsize <= 0) {
            break;
        }
```

RSA(Header)

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "ServerClass.h"
class Encryption
{
public:
    Encryption();
    ~Encryption();
    int sum = 1;
    int first;
    int second;
    int pub_Key_First; //n 공개기 및 개인키
    int eulerPi;
    int pub_Key_Second; //e 공개키
    int pri_Key; //d 개인키

    int decrypt;
    int word;

    char encrypt[BUFSIZE]; //BUFSIZE
    char encryptDone[BUFSIZE];
    char decryptDone[BUFSIZE];

    void Selectpq();
    void SelectEulerETC();
    void Enc(char buffer[], int bufsize);
    void Decryption(char buffer[], int bufsize);
    void SelectPriKey();
};
```

Comment: *"is there a better way?"* - With cryptography **anything** is better than rolling your own. Particularly true for developers hoping to fit 2048 bits of information inside a 32-bit integer value.

Comment: @IInspectable 
I don't understand Isn't the 32-bit integer value from 0 to 4294967295, right?

Comment: An unsigned 32-bit integer value can represent values from 0 through 4294967295. [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) typically uses key sizes between 2048 and 4096 bits, not 32 bits. Cryptography implementations employ [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) libraries for this. A 32-bit RSA key can be broken using a naive brute-force attack in *seconds*.

Comment: Keys are typically an array of bytes. If you look at keys in your .ssh directory, you will see they are typically all text--usually some headers and footers, and then base64 encoded text for the actual key. If you want to give it to the customer, encode the key in base64 just like everyone else does it. ATL library has base64 encoding functions built in.